# Can I still use a damaged Magsafe power cable?

Tags: power, damage

My rabbit chewed on my Magsafe 2 power adapter. I can see the silvery wire where the rabbit peeled off the isolation yet it still works.

Can I just duct tape it and continue using it or is there any danger of damage to my laptop?

Edit:
Rabbit was objurgated otherwise he is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*With the looming possibility that any advice you get from here could cause damage to your machine, I'll prefix my answer with a **disclaimer** that you should probably confirm with an official source or advice from Apple directly.*

So long as the visible damage is limited to the insulation, you should be fine with *electrical* tape (as opposed to duct tape). The silver wire you see (likely braided) is used to prevent interference and is used as a ground.

Comment: I would add that if the insulation is crushed, the cable will overheat and it is designed to melt / safely short itself out rather than igniting, but I would take it to a reputable repair shop for a second opinion. The main danger is to fire. The personal hazard is low since it's a low voltage DC current that exists between the magsafe connector and the square plastic transformer. I have used cables with nicks and cuts - and used electrical tape rather than duct tape which can conduct electricity on occasion when I felt the risk was allowable.

Comment: And not to cause too much alarm, but you can probably watch the cable for hot spots before you tape it up and feel that things are acceptable - just realize that with nicks, it will be more likely to fail due to bending and additional crushing / abrasion.

Comment: Just to add to this, rather than just taping it up, get a drinking straw, cut a small section that is long enough to cover the damage, slice it lengthways, wrap it around the damage then tape it - this will stop it bending on the weak point after the repair.

Comment: Also, is the rabbit OK!?!

Comment: And just to add to stuffe's very good suggestion: if you don't have a straw handy, you can tape other stiffening elements like toothpicks or springs (from ballpoint pens) to or around the weak point as well.